# Will the Verify Integrity of game files save space?

Tags: steam

I have installed custom files into a game and when I pressed "Verify Integrity of game files," and everything in the game came back to normal but I was not sure if that gave space and deleted the custom files, will someone tell me?

Comment: I know for sure that it doesn't delete the mods I put in my Payday 2 directory

Comment: This depends are we talking mods, from the steam workshop?

Answer (score 0):

The "Verify Integrity of games files" will compare the version that you have on your computer with the one on the steam servers.
If you added custom files in your game , it probably did remove most of them.